# Trying to apply a slippage to amountOutMin, stuck with a large number

Tags: web3js, uniswap, bignumber

Probably a silly question. I'm trying to apply a slippage (~17%) to amountOutMin and am stuck with a large number.

As you can see here, I multiply `amountOutMin` by 0.83 several times (I don't know, maybe that's wrong) to get the value with slippage.

And of course, for the ERC20 token with 18 decimals, I'm getting such a large number, already in wei, like 3,316,000 + 18 decimals which is `3.3165647166938253e+24`.

I really stuck on converting it to the integral value, I tried in different ways, like `Number()`, `BigInt()` and so on... Doesn't really help or I'm getting a error.

```
const amountIn = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether'); // amountIn for instance 0.01 ETH
    
// get path
const path = [WETH_ADDRESS, tokenAddress];
    
// get amount out
const amounts = await routerContract.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path).call();
const amountOutMin = amounts[1] * 0.83; // set minimum amount out to 83% of expected amount out
const amountOutMinWithSlippage = web3.utils.BN((amountOutMin * 0.83).toString()); // set minimum amount out with slippage
    
console.log('debug amountOutMinWithSlippage: ', amountOutMinWithSlippage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `web3.utils.toBN()` instead `web3.utils.BN()`. You can read about it in the [web3.js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#tobn). It is used to convert the amount you expect to a BigNumber. Then we use `muln()` and `divn()` (optimized for integers instead `mul()` or `div()`) to perform the calculation to avoid precision loss with BigNumbers. For more details check [bn.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/).
Then use `toString()` to print it out in your `console.log`.

#### Code

```js
const amountIn = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether'); // amountIn for instance 0.01 ETH
    
// get path
const path = [WETH_ADDRESS, tokenAddress];
    
// get amount out
const amounts = await routerContract.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path).call();
const amountOutMin = web3.utils.toBN(amounts[1]).muln(83).divn(100); // set minimum amount out to 83% of expected amount out
const amountOutMinWithSlippage = amountOutMin.muln(83).divn(100); // set minimum amount out with slippage
    
console.log('debug amountOutMinWithSlippage: ',amountOutMinWithSlippage.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly! I tried `toBN()` before, but apparently the problem was the not proper calculation functions. Now I understand how to use them together with BN.

Comment: glad it helped you!